# install desktop on base

Tags: system-installation

So I messed up when installing from the `net` installer and only installed the `system utils`. After thinking Ubuntu wasn't booting I discovered <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> so at least I did something right, What package(s) do I need for a normal Ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install or have tasksel installed you can use that to select the ubuntu desktop package:

```
sudo tasksel
```

Which will give you an interface to select and install metapackages as the netinstall image does when you insall the system.

More information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel